# What is the use of nodejs in angularjs2

Tags: node.js, angular

What is the use of `nodejs` in `angularjs2`? Without using `nodejs` & `npm` can we develop projects in `angularjs2`?

Answer (score 2):

Yes but it would be extremely difficult.

Angular2 has the expectation that you are going to use ES6 to compile typescript into Javascript.  Without Node/NPM, you will have to manage the compilation manually, which will exceedingly add to your development timeline.

Having Node and NPM will allow you to rapidly develop and compile your application.